# File IO for a rails application running on ubuntu

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, io

- 50 "netcdf" ( raster data ) files ranging from 1MB to 500MB
- passing in a given Lat / Lng
- returning an int value

The current application passes in a lat/lng in through AJAX. It opens the file, reads out the value for the input lat / lng then closes the file.

Should I be doing it this way? Or should I be opening all of the files once and simply leaving them open?

The lat/lng are generated from click on a google map ... for which there could be upwards of 2 ajax POSTs / second.  At current the file opening and closing hasn't crashed or slowed the machine noticeably ... however I'm after the best practice in a situation as this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not import the contents of the files into a database instead?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the data you have and how much it will change or needs to be updated.

If the data is not going to change, then the right way to do it is to extract all the data into a database and query what you need.